# How to convert JSON Array integer variable to string

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am having issues parsing my integer values from JSON to String so I can add it to an array list.

I have tried using `Integer.valueOf` but I am a bit stuck on the formatting for this particular issue and whether `Integer.valueOf` will actually work or not.

This is the code I have that works so far

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    vehicleMakes = new String[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        String make = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("make").toString();
        String model = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("model").toString();
        String reg = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("license_number").toString();
        // int year = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString();

        Vehicle V = new Vehicle(make, model, reg);
        vehicleArrayList.add(V);
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am trying to add integer variables with this, such as

```
int year = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString();
```

How can I add this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the library you use, but if it's org.json, you could try something like this:

```
int year = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("year");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int year = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("year");
String strYear = String.valueOf(year);
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at this line:

```
int year = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString();
```

Your trying to add an integer and a string, as java is a typed language this wont work and youll likely get a compile time error flagged by the compiler, to resolve this youve got a few options, my suggestion is this:

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(yourString) // good option, will account for ascii codes ang give you the correct value

// now convert to a string like so:

String.valueOf(result);

// so your code would be:

int year = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert String to int with

```
Integer.parseInt(string);
Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] toStringArray(JSONArray array) {
if(array==null)
    return null;

String[] arr=new String[array.length()];
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i]=array.optString(i);
}
return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If compiler doesn't recognise this way, add org.json library.

Example:

```
String year = String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("year"));
```

or in your case:

```
String year = String.valueOf(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("year"));
```